# Is there a way to enable/disable Smart::Comments via a command line switch in my Perl program?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'd like to enable/disable the comments within my Perl program that make use of the module Smart::Comments. I've toyed with the idea of doing this by providing a --verbose switch as part of my list of command line options. When this switch is set, I was thinking of enabling the Smart::Comment module like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Getopt::Long;
use Smart::Comments;

my $verbose = 0;
GetOptions ('verbose' => \$verbose);

if (! $verbose) {
  eval "no Smart::Comments";
}
### verbose state: $verbose
```

However this doesn't work for me. It seems to be something with the way Smart::Comments itself works, so I'm suspicious of the way in which I'm trying to disable the module with the eval "no ..." bit. Can anyone offer me some guidance on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take out the `use Smart::Comments` line out of the script, and run you script with or without the `-MSmart::Comments` option. Using the `-M<module>` option is like putting a `use <module>` statement at the beginning of your script.

```
# Smart comments off
$ perl my_script.pl

# Smart comments on
$ perl -MSmart::Comments my_script.pl ...
```

---

Also see the [`$ENV{Smart_Comments}`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart%3a%3aComments#CONFIGURATION_AND_ENVIRONMENT) variable in the `Smart::Comments` docs. 
Here, you would use `Smart::Comments` in your script like

```
use Smart::Comments -ENV;
```

and then run

```
$ perl my_script.pl 
$ Smart_Comments=0 perl my_script.pl
```

to run without smart comments, and

```
$ Smart_Comments=1 perl my_script.pl
```

to run with smart comments.

---

**Update** The `Smart::Comments` module is a source filter. Trying to turn it on and off at runtime (e.g., `eval "no Smart::Comments"`) won't work. At best, you can do some configuration at compile time (say, in a `BEGIN{}` block, before loading `Smart::Comments`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN { $ENV{Smart_Comments} = " @ARGV " =~ / --verbose / }
use Smart::Comments -ENV;
...
```

Comment: Yeah I'd rather hide that from users of my script. Also I don't run this script using perl ... <myscript.pl>, I'm making the script executable and running it directly.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense that Smart::Comments can't be turned on/off at runtime via an eval block. I was trying to figure out how to make use of a BEGIN block and coming up empty, that's the best approach I've seen yet for getting what I want!

Comment: It's not because it's a source filter that `no Smart::Comments;` doesn't work. It could look for `no Smart::Comments;` and pass code through unchanged until it encounters `use Smart::Comments;`. For example, [feature::qw_comments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature::qw_comments) is a keyword plugin (similar to a source filter) that uses this concept of loaded-but inactive to lexically scope its effect.

Comment: @ikegami - I don't understand your comment. A `no Smart::Comments` statement does exactly what you describe -- if it is encountered at compile-time. At run time, the scope of `eval "no Smart::Comments"` is limited to the `eval` statement -- it can only disable smart comments within the eval statement. Maybe that still "works"; it's just not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use "if" pragma:

```
use if !$ENV{MY_APP_NDEBUG}, 'Smart::Comments';
# or
use if $ENV{MY_APP_DEBUG}, 'Smart::Comments';
```

This doesn't load Smart::Comments if not required.